# Solve for the roots in the following equations

Tags: roots

I have two equalities:
$$ \alpha x^{2} + \alpha y^{2} - y = 0 $$
$$ \beta  x^{2} + \beta y^{2} - x = 0 $$

Where $$ \alpha, \beta $$ are both known constants.

How can I solve for $x$ and $y$?

Comment: Welcome to math SE. What have you tried?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please include your own thoughts and the effort made thus far, so that people can work with you accordingly. (Please add those in the body of the question instead of commenting.)

Answer (score 1):

The two curves are circles through the origin and they will intersect in at most one other point.

By eliminating $x^2+y^2$, we have

$$\beta y=\alpha x,$$

then

$$\beta(\beta x^2+\beta y^2-x)=(\beta^2 + \alpha^2)x^2 -\beta x = 0. $$

The rest is immediate.

> $$\left(\frac\beta{\beta^2+\alpha^2},\frac\alpha{\beta^2+\alpha^2}\right).$$

We also have the special case $\alpha=\beta=0$, which is trivial.

Answer (score -1):

The number of solutions  depends on how many of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are zero.

- For any $\alpha$ and $\beta$, $x = y = 0$ is a (trivial) solution.
- $\alpha = \beta = 0$: Only the trivial solution occurs.
- $\alpha \neq 0$ or $\beta \neq 0$ (or both): A nontrivial solution also appears, $x = \frac{\beta}{\alpha^2 + \beta^2}$ and $y = \frac{\alpha}{\alpha^2 + \beta^2}$.